# Constructing concrete types for typeclasses with GADTs

Tags: haskell, typeclass, gadt

The inspiration for this is creating a list of values that are instances of `Show`. I found the following snippet that uses GADTs to create a concrete `Showable` type.

```
data Showable where Showable :: Show a => a -> Showable

instance Show Showable where
    show (Showable x) = show x

list :: [Showable]
list = [Showable 4, Showable "hello", Showable 'a']
```

Then, I tried to make `Showable` more general by creating a type that could make any typeclass concrete.

```
data Concrete a where Concrete :: a b => b -> Concrete a

instance Show (Concrete Show) where
    show (Concrete x) = show x

list :: [Concrete Show]
list = [Concrete 4, Concrete "hello", Concrete 'a']
```

This works with the ConstraintKinds and FlexibleInstances language extensions, but in order to use `Concrete` to make concrete types for other typeclasses, each one would require a new instance.

Is there a way to create something similar to `Concrete` such that, for example, `Concrete Show` is automatically an instance of `Show`?

Comment: Since `Concrete` is a *type constructor* and `Show` is a *type class*, the expression `Concrete Show` isn't even legal, much less an instance of anything. I might be wrong, but I'm going to suggest you won't ever get this to work.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid It already did work, with ConstraintKinds and FlexibleInstances. I added this to the question.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Now you can, since the kinding system allows `Show :: * -> Constraint`, and you can parametrize a type with such kind, as done above.

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea such craziness is possible. Next they'll be adding language extensions that make the type system Turing-complete... oh, wait.

Comment: I don't think this is doable. It would require something like `instance c (Concrete c)`. Also, don't forget that `[Showable]` is a known [antipattern](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) since it is an overcomplication of `[String]`.

Comment: @afuous I found it instructive to play around with the function `breakConcrete :: (forall a. c a => a -> r) -> Concrete c -> r;
breakConcrete f (Concrete x) = f x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible. Consider this:

```
instance Monoid (Concrete Monoid) where
   mappend (Concrete x) (Concrete y) = Concrete (mappend x y) -- type error!
```

This is a type error since `x` and `y` come from two different existential quantifications. There is no guarantee that `x` and `y` can be added together.

In other words, `[Concrete [1,2], Concrete ["hello"]]` has type `[Concrete Monoid]` but can not be summed (`mconcat`).

---

This is precisely the same problem for which, in OOP, the following base class/interface does not work:

```java
interface Vector {
   Vector scale(double x);
   Vector add(Vector v);
}
class Vec2D implements Vector { ... }
class Vec3D implements Vector { ... }
```

The interface implies that a 2D vector is addable to any other vector, including a 3D one, which makes no sense. For an OOP solution, see [F-bounded quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification) and its related popularization callled [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

In Haskell, we often do not need such techniques since there is no subtyping, hence two types in, say, a `Vector` type class are already not mixable.

```
class Vector a where
   scale :: Double -> a -> a
   add :: a -> a -> a
instance Vector (Vec2D) where ...
instance Vector (Vec3D) where ...
```

Comment: So this is why in Java, it is `Thing implements Comparable<Thing>` and not just `Thing implements Comparable`. This is a good answer.

Comment: @afuous Yes, exactly.